# Adding appwidget of application just after its installation

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have installed a receiver application on device which listen to the package added intent and executes code when my application is installed

Now I want that receiver to put appwidget of the application on homescreen

Please let me know how it can be done or is there any other way to put appwidget at the time of app installation

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want that receiver to put appwidget of the application on homescreen

Fortunately, this is not possible. The user adds app widgets to the home screen, not you.

Comment: People are doing this so i think its possible,i just want to know how to implement this kind of functionality

Comment: @SurbhiDhingra: Name any that do this.